# Given a URL and HTTP verb, how can I resolve the controller/action in ASP.NET MVC/Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Let's say that I have a controller with two actions, RouteOne (GET) and RouteTwo (POST).  I also have the default route registered, so if the controller is HomeController, I should be able to get to the controller by going to this URL in a browser:

> GET Home/RouteOne

The question: Given an URL and an HTTP verb, how can I get a reference to the MethodInfo of the controller action I'm trying to run?  This includes actions that use query string parameters.

Example: this action inside of the HomeController:

```
[HttpGet] public ActionResult AnAction(string param1, int param2) {}
```

should be resolved with an HTTP verb of GET and a URL of:

> Home/AnAction?param1=asdf&param2=1234

The ultimate goal is to determine whether or not someone has access to a given URL, using the AuthorizeAttribute to provide role information.  If there's another way to determine this, I'm all ears.

Comment: Why do you need methodinfo to tell you that? Are you trying to unit test the Authorize attribute?

Comment: Are you trying to determine permissions on the client side? A user can tell they don't have access when the server rejects their request. have your api return a 403 Forbidden code.

Comment: That's already built in through the attribute, but if you are trying to hide the link, it's better to setup permissions the user does and doesn't have, store them as claims (in the user identity object) and then check the claims within the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this will help and it *might be considered a bad practice* but what I did before was create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` and decorate relevant Actions with it to determine whether logged in user is authorized to access that Action and if not redirect to homepage. Maybe this can give you some ideas.

```
public class RoleAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(urlHelper.Action("Index", "Authentication"));
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var permission = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var user = httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true ? ((MyUserIdentity)httpContext.User.Identity) : null;

        if (user == null)
            return false;

        if (permission.Equals("Home"))
            return true;

        int count = 0;
        using (var con = new myAppEntities())
        {
            var permissionid = con.permissions.Where(p => p.PermissionName.Equals(permission)).Single().PermissionId;
            count = con.rolepermissions.Where(rp => rp.PermissionId == permissionid && rp.RoleId == user.RoleId).Count();
        }

        if (count > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```